# Batch Script to SSH and deploy cron job via VI

Tags: batch-file, cron, vi, jobs

First i would just like to point out, i know very little about this subject matter.  Okay, now that that is out of the way.

I am trying to setup a batch script to ssh to a list of IP's (about 50) and create a simple cron job to reboot the box it connects to every 24 hours at midnight local time.

I already create the cron job in VI, but i have no idea how to make this batch script work.  I have tried to piece meal a batch together but, have had zero luck.  Lastly i think i should mention that i am making the batch file on a windows box, and sshing to a Linux shell. If their is anything you guys need let me know and i will try to supply it.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: for clarity

Answer (score 0):

May this be useful?

### [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18275697/get-two-different-outputs-from-a-ping-request-in-a-batch-file)

Inside the "commands.txt used in the script i linked to:

```
shutdown -r -t sec 0 Rebooting
exit
```