# Get two different outputs from a ping request in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, command, output, ping

im working on a script that is supposed to sort out ping requests.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /L %%i IN (60,1,254) DO ping -n 1 10.100.121.%%i & IF %%i==Reply (
ECHO 10.100.121.%%i>>c:\Test\Online.txt
  ) ELSE (
ECHO 10.100.121.%%i>>c:\Test\Offline.txt
  )
pause
```

But it doesn't seem to be working as it should. All IP addresses goes to the offline.txt file, even if they are online.

What have i done wrong?

If someone is very kind, then I wonder if I can run this command with the "%online_ip%" variabel for each ping request being online and those who are not online are sent to offline.txt

```
C:\Test\putty.exe "%online_ip%" -l "root" -pw "pw" -m C:\Test\Commands.txt
```

---

### EDIT:

#### The "improved" version of **foxidrive's** solution!

```
@echo off
FOR /L %%i IN (60,1,254) DO (
   echo  Checking if host at 10.100.121.%%i is Online.
   ping -n 1 10.100.121.%%i >nul 
    if not errorlevel 1 (
      echo  Host is Online & echo  Starting SSH with Plink at 10.100.121.%%i & echo.
      echo y | plink.exe root@10.100.121.%%i -pw password -m c:\Test\Commands.txt
    ) else (
      echo  Host is Offline & echo.
      >>c:\Test\Offline.txt ECHO 10.100.121.%%i
   )
)
pause
```

Comment: `%%i` is your "counter" - an integer. It will never be `Reply`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See how this works for you:

```
@echo off
FOR /L %%i IN (60,1,254) DO (
   echo pinging 10.100.121.%%i
   ping -n 1 10.100.121.%%i >nul 
    if not errorlevel 1 (
      echo running putty with 10.100.121.%%i
      C:\Test\putty.exe "%%i" -l "root" -pw "pw" -m C:\Test\Commands.txt
    ) else (
      echo 10.100.121.%%i offline
      >>c:\Test\Offline.txt ECHO 10.100.121.%%i
   )
)
pause
```

Comment: Thanks!! I had to do a few changes to get it working and look a bit better. I also swapped putty with plink (command-line version of putty), to get rid of the putty gui and make it easier. The code is added at the bottom of my question :)